# AOSP Android compile sourcecode on Mac

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

According to Android guideline：
1. download repo
2. repo init
3. repo sync
I got sourcecode of Android 7.1.1 in the disk
problem came when lunching combo

```
You're building on Darwin

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
 1. aosp_arm-eng
 2. aosp_arm64-eng
 3. aosp_mips-eng
 4. aosp_mips64-eng
 5. aosp_x86-eng
 6. aosp_x86_64-eng
 7. full_fugu-userdebug
 8. aosp_fugu-userdebug
 9. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
 10. m_e_arm-userdebug
 11. m_e_mips-userdebug
 12. m_e_mips64-eng
 13. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
 14. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
 15. aosp_dragon-userdebug
 16. aosp_dragon-eng
 17. aosp_marlin-userdebug
 18. aosp_sailfish-userdebug
 19. aosp_flounder-userdebug
 20. aosp_angler-userdebug
 21. aosp_bullhead-userdebug
 22. hikey-userdebug
 23. aosp_shamu-userdebug

Which would you like? [aosp_arm-eng] 
-bash: Saving: command not found
-bash: ...saving: command not found
-bash: ...completed.: command not found

** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_arm'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

OSX:10.11.6
jdk:1.8.0_101
Xcode:8.2.1
I'm not sure how to deal with it. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Each lunch combo has **product specs** defined inside `device/company_name/device_name/device.mk`. For E.g `device/moto/shamu/device.mk` is defined for **Nexus 6**.

> ** Don't have a product spec for: 'aosp_arm'
>
> ** Do you have the right repo manifest?

As error says, no product spec defined for 'aosp_arm'

For more info, refer [Adding a new Device](https://source.android.com/source/add-device#prod-def)

Comment: Thanks bro, I had those mk files in each company dirs. And I read the Adding a new Device doc and found this at the beginning "Please note, unlike the other pages in this section, the contents here are applicable only when creating an entirely new device type and are intended for company build and product teams only." if I just wanna run the default source code on a default emulator, is there anything I shall give a try?

Comment: Have you tried other lunch options, they should also work on a default emulator.

Comment: I tried from 1 to 23, none of them worked :-(  But follow the same step, it works on Ubuntu

Comment: any update how to fix it ? I am facing the same issue